# Android: Are files in /res/raw viewable by the end user?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android app and I have a bunch of static configuration that I load from /res/raw. I'm wondering if these files are accessible by the user? If so, can they be modified by the user as well? While my app will be interacting with these files, I don't want the end user to be able to manually manipulate them.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering if these files are accessible by the user?

They are publicly visible to all applications. Users typically would not have an application that would allow browsing of such resources, but such an app is certainly possible.

> If so, can they be modified by the user as well?

Resources are read-only for everybody, including you for your own app, while the app is on the device. However, users could grab the APK off the device, decompile it, change resources, recompile it, and install the modified edition. Again, most users would not have the skills to do that, but it is certainly possible.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in any client device can be reader and manipulated. That's why something is executed in client device.